# How to check if serial-over-lan is supported in my PC?

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, intel

I need to check if ME software is working properly on my PC. I've already checked AMT and LMS and they're both running. I just need to check that SOL is also supported/existing in my PC. I can't connect to a DHCP server right now so I can't check connection via SOL using that method.

When I checked supporting documents for Windows, I found that this can be done by installing Intel® Management Engine software and checking that Serial Ports\"Intel Active Management Technology - Serial Over LAN (COMx) is listed in the Device Manager.

Is there a method like this for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much checking, I found that it could be checked by simply running lspci and checking if something like ‘00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation’ exists (depending on the platform)